# Fast space efficient data structure for set membership queries on small sets

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, language-agnostic, set

I am trying to create a data structure for a fixed size set that should support the following operations:

1. Query whether an element is in the set (false positives are ok, false negatives are not)
2. Replace one element of the set with another element

In my case, the size of the set is likely to be very small (4-16 elements), but the lookups must be as fast as possible and read as few bits as possible. Also, it needs to be space efficient. Replacements (i.e. operation 2) are likely to be few. I looked into the following options:

1. **Bloom Filters**: This is the standard solution. However, it is difficult to delete elements and as such difficult to implement operation 2.
2. **Counting Bloom Filters**: The space requirement becomes much higher (~ 3-4x) of that of the standard Bloom filter for no decrease in false +ve rates.
3. **Simply storing a list of hashes of all the elements**: Gives better false +ve rates than counting bloom filter for similar space requirements, but is expensive to look up (in worst case all bits will be looked up).
4. **Previous idea with perfect hashing for location**: I don't have an idea about fast perfect hashes for small sets of elements.

Additional Information:

- The elements are 64 bit numbers.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: What sort of elements are in the set? Small numbers? Big numbers? Strings? Circus elephants?

Comment: They are big numbers, each 64 bits.

Comment: Without testing it is hard to say for certain of course, but storing them in an array and simply doing a binary lookup will give you `log(n)` lookup performance and replacements are `O(1)`

Comment: It should be noted that said array has to be sorted of course.

Comment: @Wolph Replacement is `O(n)` in order to maintain the array sorted. [Otherwise you could do a sort in `O(n)`]

Comment: If this is not a microcontroller, I'd go with the hash. You can check a vector of 16 8-bit hashes in a single x64 instruction. That would have an annoyingly high false +ve rate -- around 65% I think -- but in a common case, it would indicate exactly one potential match, which would just be one more comparison, this time 64 bits. That's a total of 192 bits for common cases. Is that too high?

Comment: I will also like to minimize the amount of bits read. We could have had the same functionality with a simple bloom filter which uses 4 bits per element thus requiring only 64 bits to get a much lower false +ve rate. But replacements will then be a hassle. Ideally, I will just like some ideas which I can then test out according to the actual read/write ratio.

Comment: Sure, the bloom filter is a lot cheaper in terms of bit reads. But counting bloom filters aren't, and the the replace operation is trivial with the hash, while with counting bloom filters its only annoying and with simple bloom filters it pretty well requires rebuilding.

Comment: @amit: true, you would have to be lucky for a better sort. Perhaps a list/array combo would be better in that case

Comment: How about a [Judy array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judy_array)?

Comment: Sorry, 65% is false+ve for **4**-bit hashes. With 8-bit hashes, it's around 6%. If you check the hashes and then, if the correct hash is present exactly once, compare that value (the 192-bit case), then the likelihood of false+ve drops to around 0.18%. You can arrange for the first 128-bit read to be a single cache-line, but around 3.5% of the time the 64-bit value-check will be in a different cache-line (could be higher depending on how you layout your data; of course, it's lower if the set doesn't contain 16 elements.)

Comment: You say replacements are likely to be few. How few, in comparison to the lookups? If it's few enough, you could just set up a new bloom filter every time and not worry about the erasures...

Answer (score 5):

Cuckoo Filter is an option that should be considered. To quote their abstract

*Cuckoo Filter: Practically Better Than Bloom*

> We  propose a new data structure called the cuckoo filter that can replace Bloom filters for approximate set member-ship tests. Cuckoo filters support **adding and removing items dynamically** while achieving even **higher performance than Bloom filters**.  For applications that store many items and
>   target moderately low false positive rates, **cuckoo filters have lower space overhead than space-optimized Bloom filters. Our experimental results also show that cuckoo filters out-perform previous data structures that extend Bloom filters to support deletions substantially in both time and space.

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dga/papers/cuckoo-conext2014.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Well, note the following:

1. Using standard hash table, with a descent hash function (since it is numbers, there are bunch of standard hash functions) with 4|S| entries will require on average less then 2 look-ups (assuming unbiased numbers as input), though it might deteriorate to terrible worst case of 4|S|. Of course you can bound it as follows:

     -  If number of cells searched exceeds `k` - abort and return true (will cause FP at some probability that you can caclculate, and will give faster worst case performance).
2. Regarding counting bloom filters - this is the way to do it, IMO. Note that a bloom filter (standard) requires 154 bits to have FP probability of 1%, or 100 bits to have FP probability of 5%. (*)

   So, if you need 4 times this number, you get 616 bits / 400 bits, Note that in most modern machine this is small enough to fill a few CPU-Cache blocks, which means (depending on the machine) - reading all these bits could really take less then 10 cycles on some machines.

   IMO you cannot do anything to beat it without getting much higher FP rate.

(*) [Calculated according to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter#Probability_of_false_positives):

> m = n ln(p) / ln(2)<sup>2</sup>

**P.S.** If you can guarantee each element is removed at most once, you can use a variation of bloom filter with double space instead that has slightly better FP, but also has some FNs, by simply using 2 bloom filters: 1 for `regular` and 1 for `deleted`. An element is in the set if it is in `regular` and NOT in `deleted`.

This improves FP rate at the expense of having also FNs

Comment: The dual bloom counter idea also came to my mind. I will check it out.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the 16 64 bit numbers occupy a total of 1024 bits, so a 616-bit counting bloom filter is 60% of the data size. If a cache-line is 512 bytes, both the bloom filter and the full data would equally require two cache fills, and letting the data represent itself is commputationally a lot simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Check out `succinct data structures`, for example *[Membership in Constant Time and Minimum Space](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0049398)*.

> There are many situations in dealing with a subset chosen from the
>   bounded universe, in which the size of the subset is relatively big
>   but not big enough to use a bit map.